# Unloading horse from a minecart!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to travel across a river, I had minecart track going across to my base over the river, so I decided to use them. however while riding the horse over that bridge horse accidentally got loaded in the minecart, now I can't destroy the minecart because when I attack minecart horse gets hurt.

Things tried.

- Pushed the minecart to the station and tried to destroy tracks at the station and then tried attacking minecart but still horse got hurt. after placing the tracks back I accidently pushed the minecart inside a wooden block.
- I started searching over the internet for unloading horses got at this page "[Unloading animals from minecarts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121897/unloading-animals-from-minecarts)" then Implemented that solution, however, I am not able to give velocity to the minecart because it is off track.

See the image below for more clear picture of situation:

**What could be a possible solution to remove horse from minecart without damaging the horse? (It is okay if I lose the minecart.)**

[image]

Comment: What Minecraft version are you using? I assume 1.9, because of the boat texture.

Comment: You assumed correctly

Comment: Oh yeah! And the shield.

Comment: I'd use lava to "unload" the horse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Mine the Rail underneath the horse in the minecart. (So that it won't move.)
2. Put your cursor in position so that it is in the lower part of the minecart.
   [image: YAY]
3. Mine away!

Comment: Destroyed the sand block below the wood block, then removed the wood block and added rails then added minecart back to track. now minecart went one block down http://i.imgur.com/auULRLi.png but the horse was not unloaded. now I quickly destroyed the minecart with axe

Comment: I think that was a glitch

Answer (score 1):

i'm a few months late, but just in case someone else needs an answer to the same question:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Activator_Rail

alternatively, if you're playing a desktop edition, make a creative test world (because i haven't tried this), put a mob or an animal into a minecart and type a kill command with a @type selector set to target minecarts. if the passenger isn't killed too, go to your main world and fix things that way.

Comment: Cheats are disabled in main world.

Comment: At that time I didn't tried activator rails. But just after That incident I did modify the railway system with activator rails.