# Automated way to transfer a villager from a minecart to a water stream?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Question about says it.  I'm stumped, and have tried a number of different techniques for getting a villager to get out of a minecart, and into a water stream, and I can't figure it out.  Is it possible?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102974/how-can-i-break-a-minecart-with-the-environment-without-destroying-it

Comment: Yes, I remembered this, but that's only half of the problem, the other half is to get the villager to get into the stream.

Comment: Well that should be as simple as setting up a tripwire or pressure plate where they land that triggers a piston.

Comment: Note: In version 1.8 there are much better ways to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, though slowly. It could be improved with more engineering but that might best be done in the specific situation you want to use this mechanism. Tested in release 1.7.4.

[image]

The carts come in on the rail line (towards the camera) and hit the cactus, breaking. Hoppers underneath return the cart to storage. The zombie encourages the villager to move left, walking on to the open trap door (there is an opening to the outer world to the left of it) and falling down into the water instead. Notes:

- If the trap door trick stops working, you could use a tripwire to pull out the ground with a piston, or similar tricks. The key is that there is a spot of apparently-reachable solid ground for the villager to decide to walk to, which then turns out to actually dump them in the water stream.
- I'm not sure whether the zombie is actually helping. I'm pretty sure you *can* use zombies to scare villagers into moving, but I don't know if this specific arrangement actually does so.
- Based on snapshots, it is expected that in future versions of Minecraft an Activator Rail can be used to eject minecart riders; this does not change the getting-into-water problem but removes the need for the cactus and hoppers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the minecart when the villager is in/near the water. Also, if you aren't already, use a powered rail so you won't have to push the minecart around.

Comment: I am looking for a bit more detail.  Breaking minecarts is known, but getting villagers contained therein to transition to water is not obvious.

Comment: Can you tell me why you need to get the villager into the water? Also, what is keeping him from getting into/near the water?

Answer (score 0):

Use an activator rail, and put glass above the activator rail and the rails next to it, to make sure there is only one place where the villager can be ejected, which is on the same level as the rail. Then, put a sign on the ejection spot and a water source block above it.

The villager will be ejected on the block under the water source block, and float up. This even works for babies; they touch the water when they get ejected and float up, rather than standing under the water source block.

(12.2.2)